# WebEngine isn't loading anything

Tags: java, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

No errors whatsoever, it just doesn't display anything and when I try and debug the loaded page's title it returns null.

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    WebView view = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
    engine.load("http://www.google.com/");


    Scene scene = new Scene(view, 800, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: It works for me. How is your Internet settings? Do you use proxy?

Comment: Your code should work. Try loading a different URL or even local file, to check it works. Also you can track the loading state. Check for `engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()`.